# d3.json not from .json file

Tags: d3.js, meteor

I'm trying to create map markers using d3.  The example I found uses and external json file, which works fine.  But, now I want that data to come from a Meteor collection.  I tried various ways to parse it and pass it to d3.json, but it seems to only work with get requests.  I can't seem to find how to use an array of objects instead of the file.

In the sample code below, how can I replace the d3.json with something that loops through the collection and creates the overlay/markers?

I included the meteor stub data so you can see what it looks like.

```
Meteor.methods({

addOverlay:function(){

    if(Meters.find().count() === 0){
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'100',lat:35.3388083059,lon:-93.1454246508,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'101',lat:35.3169395071,lon:-93.1954692058,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'102',lat:35.2644570125,lon:-93.1077845936,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'103',lat:35.2914490482,lon:-93.1366128962,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'104',lat:35.2924845706,lon:-93.137011747,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'105',lat:35.2396527486,lon:-93.1642136476,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'106',lat:35.2644570125,lon:-93.1077845936,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'107',lat:35.2906449082,lon:-93.1521390443,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'108',lat:35.2696120589,lon:-93.086017034,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'109',lat:35.2396279862,lon:-93.1641801796,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'110',lat:35.3482378546,lon:-93.1273660845,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'111',lat:35.2274058217,lon:-93.1328221341,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'112',lat:35.305158332,lon:-93.1342573029,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'113',lat:35.300761757,lon:-93.2101460287,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'114',lat:35.3003676128,lon:-93.1373398967,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'115',lat:35.3404693793,lon:-93.1294158351,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'116',lat:35.2708616654,lon:-93.1024375811,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'117',lat:35.2780495131,lon:-93.0928600071,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'118',lat:35.2337794997,lon:-93.1500096575,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'119',lat:35.3094147618,lon:-93.2295004202,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'120',lat:35.2738985803,lon:-93.09200206,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'121',lat:35.2266244862,lon:-93.1484123911,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'122',lat:35.2810259995,lon:-93.1359737857,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'123',lat:35.2914869223,lon:-93.1363450615,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'124',lat:35.3004608705,lon:-93.1373598895,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'125',lat:35.2792596439,lon:-93.106642839,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'126',lat:35.2919249356,lon:-93.1127959135,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'127',lat:35.2595017845,lon:-93.1065085235,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'128',lat:35.2644233341,lon:-93.0954487854,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'129',lat:35.2660235514,lon:-93.1024842513,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'130',lat:35.2840469865,lon:-93.1648804978,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'131',lat:35.2867568159,lon:-93.1696579154,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'132',lat:35.3259788748,lon:-93.1360856659,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'133',lat:35.2947439872,lon:-93.1369003164,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'134',lat:35.2517935514,lon:-93.1347987317,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'135',lat:35.2396527486,lon:-93.1642136476,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'136',lat:35.2612222251,lon:-93.0650250256,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'137',lat:35.2896194507,lon:-93.1382156146,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'138',lat:35.3023002702,lon:-93.1350752338,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'139',lat:35.2730480568,lon:-93.1449718513,status:'red'});
        Meters.insert({umsNumber:'140',lat:35.2838665706,lon:-93.1486751347,status:'red'});


    }

var markerData = Meters.find({}).fetch();

var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(markerData)) ;

    d3.json(json, function (data) {
        var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

        overlay.onAdd = function () {
            var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget).append("div")
                .attr("class", "markers");


            overlay.draw = function () {
                var projection = this.getProjection(),
                    padding = 10;

                var marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
                    .data(d3.entries(data))
                    .each(transform)
                    .enter().append("svg:svg")
                    .each(transform)
                    .attr("class", "marker")


                marker.append("svg:circle")
                    .attr("r", 4.5)
                    .attr("cx", padding)
                    .attr("cy", padding)

                marker.append("svg:text")
                    .attr("x", padding + 7)
                    .attr("y", padding)
                    .attr("dy", ".31em")
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.umsNumber;
                    });



                function transform(d) {
                    d = new google.maps.LatLng(d.lat, d.lon);
                    d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);
                    return d3.select(this)
                        .style("left", (d.x - padding) + "px")
                        .style("top", (d.y - padding) + "px");
                }

                 d3.selectAll(".marker").on("click", function(e){
                  alert( e.umsNumber )
                  console.log(e);

                 });
            };
        };

        overlay.setMap(map);

    })
```

}

});

Comment: got it working myself by removing d3.json and just passing the fetch straight to data

    .data(d3.entries(markerData))